# RavenDB full-text search dictionaries using IRavenQueryable

Tags: linq, lucene, full-text-search, ravendb

please advise me on how to correctly conduct a full-text search on a dictionary field.

I have indexed all translatable fields like this:

```cs
public class TranTest
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Trans1 { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> Trans2 { get; set; }

    //for index queries
    public IDictionary<string, string> Trans { get; set; }
}

public class TranTestIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<TranTest>
{
    public TranTestIndex()
    {
        Map = docs =>
            from doc in docs
            select new
            {
                _ = doc.Trans1.Select(x => CreateField("Trans_" + x.Key, x.Value)),
                Trans2 = doc.Trans2.Select(x => CreateField("Trans_" + x.Key, x.Value)),
                /* etc. */
            };

        Index("Trans_en", FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index("Trans_fi", FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        /* etc. */
    }
}
```

This (query translates to: Trans_en:(term)) returns correct results:

```cs
var luceneQ = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<TranTest, TranTestIndex>().Search(x => x.Trans["en"], searchTerms).ToList();
```

But I would prefer using the IRavenQueryable API. Unfortunately a similiar query in that API produces InvalidOperationException: Could not understand how to translate 'x.Trans.get_Item("en")' to a RavenDB query:

```cs
var ravenQ = session.Query<TranTest, TranTestIndex>().Search(x => x.Trans["en"], searchTerms);
results = ravenQ.ToList();  //Exception!
```

Which is odd, considering this works flawlessly (translates to: Trans_en:"term*"):

```cs
session.Query<TranTest, TranTestIndex>().Where(x => x.Trans["en"].StartsWith(searchTerms))
```

My questions regarding this issue:

1. **How would I create a multiple term full-text search query on a dictionary field with IRavenQueryable linq API?**
2. Is it possible to combine IRavenQueryable and IDocumentQuery into one query?
3. Is there a another/better way to create the index?

   - It has to support dynamically adding new languages
   - It has to support searching over a concrete language
   - Search should be conducted over multiple fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've discovered a bug.  I've verified with [these unit tests](https://gist.github.com/4526281), and submitted it to the [RavenDB issue tracker](http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RavenDB-827).

To workaround for now, either use the Lucene query approach, or (as you alluded to in your second question) you can customize the underlying DocumentQuery of the IRavenQueryable as follow:

```
session.Query<TranTest, TranTestIndex>()
       .Customize(x => ((IDocumentQuery<TranTest>) x)
                           .Search(q => q.Trans["en"], searchTerms))
```